# Ajax result seems to concatenate to previous results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function that upload a comment to a form which returns the same string and if it success, the comment is pretended to a comment box and the comment input text is cleaned.

The problem is that if the user add another comment the function with add this new comment + the past comment to the comment box, where the first comment is already displayed.

i have a walk around where before the pretend i empty the comment box but this is not the best behavior.

this is my ajax function:

```
 $("#formContent").submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

    var formdata = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: "php/comment_form.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: formdata,
            mimeTypes:"multipart/form-data",
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(result){
                $("#new_comments").empty();
                $(result).hide().prependTo("#new_comments").fadeIn(1000);
                $("input").empty();
            },error: function(){
                alert("Error");
            }
    });
    });
```

So for example i add a comment : "Hello"

The div#new_comments will display:

```
Hello
```

(Thats the result from the php form)

But if i add a new comment: "World"
Then the div#new_comment will show:

```
World
Hello
Hello
```

And so..

Why is this happening? 
I tried add a var with the result like

*var comment = result;*

Then after the comment is prepend:

*var comment = "";*

But it doesn´t work.

Any ideas?

Comment: why not set it as html ? $('#new_comment ').html(result)?

Comment: Why we are wasting time in giving answer, when people not responding.?

Comment: Im sorry guys i was away from my office this week and couldn´t test the answers. .HTML works fine for me so i marked the answer below as the correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.html("")`

```
$("#new_comments").html("")
```

Comment: it worked! i just added the fade in to give it a nice effect. thanks a lot